# Event replication on slave and Slave_IO_Running:NO

Tags: mysql

I have one master and four slaves. Whenever I created an event on master it gets replicated on all slaves.However, i am running a script on one of the slaves that takes a snapshot of the machine and saves it somewhere else. During taking a snapshot i kept the Slave_IO_Running: NO  in the script and when the snapshot gets completed the script makes Slave_IO_Running: YES and the replication start again.I just want to know that after taking a snapshot at that one slave when the Slave_IO_Running turned to YES by the script, The event I created disappears from that slave but remains there on the other slave and when I delete the event on master it produces error on that slave at which snapshot is being taken.Please just let me know the reason and the effect of Slave_IO_Running: NO on slaves.

Answer (score 1):

For non-LVM, I recommend doing

```
STOP SLAVE;  -- before taking the backup
START SLAVE;  -- after taking the backup
```

This both avoids the problem and avoids other issues.

What kind of backup is it?

- LVM "snapshot" -- I recommend stopping mysqld completely.
- mysqldump (or similar) -- be sure to add the parameter that says to dump stored routines.  (I think that will capture the `EVENT`.)